# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasMany' of undefined" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I make so many tables and want to create a relationship between them. When I call the built-in function of sequelize(orm), that is, .hasMany, it gives me the error

> Cannot read the property of .hasMany of undefined

#### File *companyModel.js*

```
const sequelize = require("sequelize");
const companyDb = require("../../config/database");

const company1 = companyDb.define("company", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  address: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  contact: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
  },
  primay_email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  website: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
  },
  deleted_at: {
    type: sequelize.DATE,
  },
  is_deleted: {
    type: sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  logo_url: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
  },
  country: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

module.exports = company1;
```

I make the relation in the below:

#### File *relation.js*

```
const user = require("./usermodal");

const customerCompany = require("./customerCompanyModel");
const customer = require("./customerModel");
const invoiceItems = require("./invoiceItemsModel");
const outlet = require("./outletModel");
const outletStock = require("./outletStockModel");
const product = require("./productModel");
const role = require("./roleModel");
const invoice = require("./invoicesModel");
const { use } = require("../../routes");
const {company} = require("./companyModel");

const relationshipt   = company.hasMany(user);
user.belongsTo(company);
role.hasOne(user);
user.belongsTo(role);

company.hasMany(product);
product.belongsTo(company);

company.hasMany(outlet);
outlet.belongsTo(company);

company.hasMany(customerCompany);
customerCompany.belongsTo(company);

outlet.hasMany(user);
user.belongsTo(outlet);

outlet.hasMany(customerCompany);
customerCompany.belongsTo(outlet);

outlet.hasMany(invoice);
invoice.belongsTo(outlet);

outlet.hasMany(outletStock);
outletStock.belongsTo(outlet);

product.hasMany(outletStock);
outletStock.belongsTo(product);

product.hasOne(invoiceItems);
invoiceItems.belongsTo(product);

customer.hasMany(customerCompany);
customerCompany.belongsTo(customer);

customer.hasMany(invoice);
invoice.belongsTo(customer);

invoice.hasMany(invoiceItems);
invoiceItems.belongsTo(invoice)

module.exports = relations;
```

But it give me this error:

[image: ERROR]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: So `company` is undefined. Where is `company` exported from the model? You probably wanted `const company = require("./companyModel");`

Comment: can you share the example how to make relationship in typescript sequelize? @epascarello

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73572843/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how you can fix it. Currently:

```js
const {company} = require("./companyModel");
```

Should be (note the removed curly braces):

```js
const company = require("./companyModel");
```

The code below is just to explain what happens; do not try to use it!

So, in your `./companyModel` you export your model as the whole `exports` object:

```js
module.exports = company1;
```

And later you include it with curly braces, which translates roughly to this:

```js
const {company} = company1;
// Or to put it differently:
const company = company1.company; // And this is the undefined value you get
```

With a proper `require` statement, it would look like this:

```js
const company = company1; // That's your model; no more undefined
```